# Intersection/collision of two rectangles in SDL2

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sdl-2

There is the obvious `SDL_IntersectRect(rect1, rect2, result)`, but this isn't working as intended. If I have a rect i want to check if another rect collides with, say this rect is `{100,100,100,100}` and my other rect is `{150, 50, 100, 100}`, this does not return true. It works if my rect is `{50,150,100,100}`. (basically what this means is a rect highlighting another one from the left works, but a rect from the right highlighting a rect from the left doesn't). Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong? Ive just setup a dummy `SDL_Rect` that is the intersection but I only use the return of the function. Are there any alternatives?

Edit: It only seems to work when the initial position of my rectangle is ABOVE and TO THE LEFT of the rect I am trying to detect if it highlights

Comment: Not sure why `SDL_IntersectRect` isn't working properly, as an alternative, you can definitely calculate the intersection yourself

Comment: Also there's `SDL_HasIntersection` if you only want to know if they are intersecting each other. However I would assume it should behave similar to `SDL_IntersectRect`

Comment: I doubt there is something wrong with SDL. Maybe the error lies somewhere else, you should post a minimal example of how you calculate the intersection.

Comment: Found the error, I had a negative width when doing a change in x coordinates. the rect was drawing but ```SDL_RenderFillRect``` was handling negative width and drawing it to the left. :^).    ```Fixed it by changing the initial X coordinate and using a positive width & height)```